# Load PDF with react and noejs in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to upload a PDF file to my server using react-form-hook but having some problem in the submit function and some type problem in the "ref" argument.

this is the code:

```
    import React, { InputHTMLAttributes } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import './Bind.scss';

export const Bind = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('picture', data.picture[0]);
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/picture', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    }).then((res) => res.json());
    alert(JSON.stringify(res));
  };

  function download(blob, filename) {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.style.display = 'none';
    a.href = url;
    a.download = filename;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }

  const loadFile = async (e) => {
    const encodedValue = encodeURIComponent('mobx-bf.png');

    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/getPdf/?fileToDownload=${encodedValue}`).then((res) => {
      res.blob().then((blob) => download(blob, 'mobx-bf.png'));
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <input ref={register} type="file" name="picture" />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
      <button onClick={(e) => loadFile(e)}>Load</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

in the red property it say:
"Type 'UseFormRegister' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef | undefined'.
Type 'UseFormRegister' is not assignable to type '(instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void'.
Types of parameters 'name' and 'instance' are incompatible.
Type 'HTMLInputElement | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
"
Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<input type="file" {...register("picture")} />` like it is done in **react-hook-form** examples?

Comment: ohhhh im so stupid. thank you very much!